# Autostart an Application only if machine is in a specific network (or location)

Tags: network, automation

I'm looking for a way to automatically start an application, but only if my machine is connected to a specific network.

So I think that I would have to find a way to either:

- Check for the correct network environment before starting the application.
- Automatically start the application on connecting to the specific network.

The goal is to run a backup/file-sync software, but only if the machine is directly connected to the office network. The software should not run (not try to backup/sync) when connected via VPN, because of the slow internet connection of the office.

Here some ways how the office network could be detected:

- Based on the network interface used (docking station, display Ethernet, USB device...)
- Based on the IP of the default gateway
- Based on the public IP of the machine

Any ideas?

Thanks.